# Shared data between sessions in php (caching)

Tags: php, caching, memcached, ram

I need to store data between different users (thus different sessions) into RAM to speed up web application written in PHP (database and filesystem are not an option).

I have been googling for couple of days, without any luck. I heard about **memcached** and **apc** but I don't really know if they are suitable for me or how to even use it.

I also need this data structure to be thread-safe (not to have race conditions and data inconsistency).

Use case:
I have a static factory function `getById($id)` which returns instance of a class. I need this function to check if instance exists first, and if it does, return it or otherwise create new one populating with data from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memcached is and distribute cache, the data cached on memcached is on the remote server, and Memcached provide CAS lock(optimistic lock), you can use it make your thread-safe application:

1. $value = $memcached->get($key, NULL, $cas);
2. business process;
3. $ret = $memcached->cas($cas, $key, $value, $exp);
4. The "cas" method will "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. The Memcached::getResultCode() will return Memcached::RES_DATA_EXISTS if the item you are trying to store has been modified since you last fetched it."

however, APC is an local cache, it implement through share memory, is it thread-safe or not I don't known

Answer (score 0):

The problem with memcached or memcache that it is only clients modules on php. You also need install server app and connect there. So you can use any other db or files. The fastest solution will be shared memory http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php
but again to enable it "compile PHP with the --enable-shmop parameter in your configure line"
so with no databases and access to php check **fopen** and **flock** functions